# Sending the bool to ```function() payable``` in another contract

Tags: solidity, transactions, remix, payable

I am trying to create a pair of contracts, let's say C1 and C2. I want to add an if...else in payable function `function() public payable{}` of C2, which works on the `bool` value returned by contract C1, when `send()`, is called from C1.

How will I be able to do it?

Maybe this code snippet helps somewhere to understand it better

```
contract target.sol{
    bool private flag=false;    
    function set0(int val) public returns(bool){
        if (val % 10 == 0) {flag0 = true;}
    }


    function transact() public returns(bool){
        if(!flag){
            // heavy computation
        }
        else{
            // light computation
        }
    }
}


contract attacker(){



    function() public payable {
        if(flag == true){
            // Do some heavy computation to generate uncomplete send    
        }

        else {
            // Do some light computation to let send pass
        }
    }

}
```

Here I want to send a transaction to `contract attacker` from `contract target`, with a bool value in the message, so that when the control lands on the payable function of the `contract attacker`, it checks for the bool value, if `true`, the computationally heavy portion gets executed, otherwise lighter one gets.

Hope that helps with the description.

**Note: I have control over `target contract` only. I can run no functions from `attacker contract`.**

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. What do you mean with "works on the bool value"? You can pass any value from a contract to another by calling some function, if you want

Comment: @LauriPeltonen, in very short, I want is there anyway, I can use `send()` to pass some bool value (true/false) to the payable function of C2. So that I can use that bool value to either do a `Computationally heavy transaction and eventually fail the transaction` or `perform a light transaction for a successful transaction`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your description, but maybe you want something like this? Here C1 sends ether to C2, and C2 then calls back into C1 to read a boolean value.

```
contract C1 {
    function pay(address whoToPay) external payable {
        require(whoToPay.send(msg.value)); // just because you said "send" instead of "transfer"

        // for gas reasons, you may instead need to use whoToPay.call.value(msg.value)("")
    }

    function getBoolValue() external pure returns (bool) {
        return true;
    }
}

contract C2 {
    function() external payable {
        if (C1(msg.sender).getBoolValue()) { ... }
    }
}
```

If this isn't what you meant, please improve your question.

Comment: Hey, @smarx. Hope the added description helps more in understanding the question.

Comment: in very short, what I want is there anyway, I can use `send()` to pass some bool value (true/false) to the payable function of C2. So that I can use that bool value to either do a `Computationally heavy transaction and eventually fail the transaction` or `perform a light transaction for a successful transaction`.